# how call a javascript code in a specific blazor page

Tags: javascript, blazor

Im converting a website in blazor,
i have a page where at the end ther's this javascript

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slider-range').slider({
          ..... more
```

How can i call it in blazor?
I did not find a solution that works

Thanx

Comment: There's nothing in that code to call.

Comment: This is an immediate function, which is automatically invoked as soon as it is defined. As far as I can guess, its purpose is to initialize, perhaps, a jQuery silder widget. With Blazor you should initialize JS objects from the OnAfterRender{Aysnc} method pair. You'll need to create a JS function which you call from Blazor, and into that function you should copy the initialization code: `$(document).ready(function () { $('#slider-range').slider({`  Do you speak JavaScript ? You surely don't speak Blazor. Search Stackoverflow for questions about using JS in Blazor. You'll find many answers by I

Comment: Im asking, if someone has advice how to have the same result as before, I aöready tried to put in a myfile.js and call it into OnAfterRender{Aysnc} with jsRuntime.InvokeAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can work, the problem is blazor does not understand `$` jquery selector, you need to replace it with `document` in `.js` script for it to work.
for example,
change `$('#slider-range').slider({`  to `document.getElementById('#slider-range').slider({` then this line will work and same for everyplace where `$` is present. And just remove it from function definition like this `(function () {`